# How to build MultiNEAT from sources?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost

I'm building MultiNEAT from source, on macOS Mojave, with Python3, and I'm hitting a snag when trying "python setup.py build_ext". I get a bunch of errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a step by step of what I'm doing from scratch, if you want to follow along in your own terminal. I'm doing all of this so others can do it themselves too, as it has taken me a while to even get here. I've gotten bits and pieces of information here and there, but there is no straight up instructions on how to build this library.

```sh
# Change things accordingly for you.
# Define work dir. Should be empty at this point.
WDIR=/Users/luis/Documents/neat
cd $WDIR
# Setup Python virtual environment and requirements.
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install psutil numpy opencv-python
# Get Boost.
# Get the url from here: https://www.boost.org/users/download/
curl -L https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.70.0/source/boost_1_70_0.tar.gz | tar -xz
cd boost_1_70_0/
# Get system Python include files with: python3-config --includes
# Put that path into this exported var.
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m
# Build Boost! This will take a bit.
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=$WDIR/boost
./b2 install
# Get MultiNEAT.
cd $WDIR
git clone https://github.com/peter-ch/MultiNEAT.git
cd MultiNEAT/
# Setup build. (Is this incomplete?)
export MN_BUILD=boost
export PREFIX=$WDIR/boost
# Build MultiNEAT!
python setup.py build_ext
# Supposedly, I'd do "python setup.py install" after, but errors are happening now :(
```

This is only the top part of when errors start happening, but most are similar:

```
In file included from src/Innovation.cpp:34:
In file included from src/Innovation.h:37:
src/Genome.h:689:19: error: expected ':'
            public void set_children()
                  ^
                  :
src/Genome.h:691:49: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('std::__1::vector<double,
      std::__1::allocator<double> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') invalid)
                for(unsigned int ix = 0; ix < 2**coord.size(); ix++){
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Both of those are "typoes" (a Java-style declaration, and probably an attempt to use a `**` power operator that doesn't exist in C++). The code needs to be fixed.

Comment: It seems like the link on the MultiNEAT website does not point to the latest build. I found [this git](https://github.com/MultiNEAT/MultiNEAT) after running into the same problems you encountered. It seems to be more up to date and includes better instructions for the install. I am not sure if it really works without those errors, as I am just setting it up myself. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works:

First install the dependencies you want to use:

- Boost 1.49 and above with Boost.Python and Boost.Serialization (optional)
- ProgressBar (Python package) (optional)
- NumPy (Python package) (optional)
- Matplotlib (Python package) (optional)
- OpenCV 2.3 and above (with Python bindings) (optional)
- Cython (if you want Python bindings)

Then clone [this git](https://github.com/MultiNEAT/MultiNEAT/)(this one seems to be older but does not throw those errors you encountered)

And finally enter the source directory and run "sudo python setup.py install"

This worked even with Python 3.7.